# How to set orientation dynamically based on devices?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Is it possible to dynamically setting the portrait mode and landscape mode ? 
For example, i need to make application workable in landscape and portrait mode for Large MDPI, Large HDPI and for Xlarge

For other resolutions such as normal hdpi,normal hdpi and other , i need only portrait mode.

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: is it possible? **yes**

Comment: I think you're confused-  the Android framework automatically detects the mode and loads the correct resources.  You only need to overload the resources if you want it to look different in some resolution/orientation

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to force such things.  You can detect the density of the device and you can load the appropriate xml file.

You can detect the density by looking at display metrics:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
```

then looking at `metrics.densityDpi`. You can then load different resources accordingly.

```
int layoutId;
switch(metrics.densityDpi) { 
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
     layoutId = R.layout.lowthingy
            break;
 case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
     layoutd = R.layout.mediumthingy
             break;
 ... (for other densities)
}
setContentView(layoutID);
```

BUT just because you can do this, doesn't mean you should.  And I really think it is not the best approach.  I really think you should [read this documentation.](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically set the orientation like this:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

and

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

You can check the screen density with:

```
switch (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) {
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
    // ...
    break;
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
    // ...
    break;
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
    // ...
    break;
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
    // ...
    break;
}
```